# basic bash command not found linux

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

Commands like ls, mv, nano, rm return a "command not found"

I think what might of caused the issue is that I've edited the .bash_profile on the server and ran a source ~/.bash_profile

Comment: Those are not bash commands.

Comment: What is the value of the PATH environment variable?

Comment: when i use echo $PATH, i get 
/home/bitnami/.composer/vendor/bin

Comment: That's your problem. You're missing standard directories like /bin, /usr/bin, etc. If it helps, my PATH on Linux Mint is: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

Comment: how would i change it back ? also, are you sure about that path... it says games in there.

Comment: Yes I am sure about that path. Typically the default path is set by the default .bashrc or similar file. Read the bash manpage to see what files are sourced in what order. Also check if you're setting PATH to "" anywhere. You'll probably want to remove that.

Comment: Thank you Cyrus. That did the trick! Would you like to post the answer so I can select yours as the best? I've actually been searching for an answer for 3 hours. Might save some people quite a bit of time in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter `PATH="/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"` and then edit your .bash_profile